# Function javascript args receive value like jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to do the same as jQuery arguments passed in functions just like this example:

```
$.jax({
    url: 'request/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (json) {
        console.log(json);
    }
});
```

I want to make a function in this similar structure, pass a function and its argument in the response.

What I'm trying:

```
var foo = function (op) {
    this.f = "";
    var args = "alone";
    this.f.call();
}

foo({
    f: function (args) {
        conosole.log(args);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this?

```
var foo = function (op) {

    op.f('hello');
}

foo({
    f: function (args) {
        console.log(args);
    }
});
```